How to add a new flow version using the Tooling API
I want to deploy a flow using Tooling API. However, if the flow already exists in the target org, I get this error :
The fullName: FlowDeploymentSample for Flow version is not unique.

Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please take a minute to read How to Ask and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to add some more detail. Have you looked at the XML metadata content of the flow? Does it have a version specification in it? Have you tried removing this? Is it specified as active?
